# Binary data is not getting stored in SQLite, returns null

Tags: sqlite, blob

Printing out the data gives me:

```
\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\t\x06\x07\x13\x13\x12\x15\x13\x13\x13\x16\x16\x15\x17\x19\x1a\x1b\x17\x16\x18\x18
```

So the binary data is present. However, when I try inserting the value with this code:

```
        for i in check_row:
            if i[0] == 0:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO profiles (profile_id, city, country, interest, bio, picture) VALUES (:user, :city, :country, :interest, :bio, :picture)",
                [user, city, country, interest, bio, empPicture])
                conn.commit()
                flash("profile completed")
                return redirect("/")
            else:
                db.execute("UPDATE profiles SET city = :city, country = :country, interest = :interest, bio = :bio, picture = :picture WHERE profile_id = :profile_id",
                [city, country, interest, bio, user, empPicture])
                conn.commit()
                flash("profile updated")
                return redirect("/profile")
```

`empPicture` is the variable holding the binary data. This returns no error however, data never gets inputted into the picture BLOB column, it just shows NULL and prints out None when ran.
This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "profiles" ( "profile_id" INTEGER, "city" TEXT VARCHAR(255), "country" TEXT VARCHAR(255), "interest" TEXT VARCHAR(255), "bio" TEXT VARCHAR(255), "picture" BLOB )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to wrap your insert into `sqlite3.Binary` as follows:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO profiles (profile_id, city, country, interest, bio, picture) VALUES (:user, :city, :country, :interest, :bio, :picture)",
[user, city, country, interest, bio, sqlite3.Binary(empPicture)])
conn.commit()
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.numericalexpert.com/blog/sqlite_blob_time/).